# Unable to load grunt, not sure what i am doing wrong or what i need to do

Tags: terminal, gruntjs

I am trying to run my first project using grunt. i am stuck at the point when i try running grunt in the command line i get an error/warning like this:

```
Traviss-MacBook-Pro-2:GRUNT Travis$ grunt compass
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-qunit" not found. Is it installed?
Warning: Task "compass" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I installed both jshint and qunit so i am lost on what to do next for fixing this problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Here is my grunt.js file

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
     concat: {
     options: {
        separator: ';'
     },
    dist: {
       src: ['src/**/*.js'],
       dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
     }
   },
   uglify: {
     options: {
       banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
     },
     dist: {
       files: {
        'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
       }
     }
   },
   qunit: {
     files: ['test/**/*.html']
   },
   jshint: {
     files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'src/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js'],
     options: {
       // options here to override JSHint defaults
       globals: {
         jQuery: true,
        console: true,
        module: true,
         document: true
      }
    }
   },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint', 'qunit']
    }
 });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-qunit');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');

  grunt.registerTask('test', ['jshint', 'qunit']);

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'qunit', 'concat', 'uglify']);

 };
```

Comment: You might want to post your Gruntfile.js for a little more context.  Also, when you say you've installed jshint and qunit, if you can provide the commands used to install them, that might be helpful, too (I'm new to grunt myself, but I believe you need to use, for example, `npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev` vs. `npm install jshint --save-dev`).

Comment: i used this line to install qunit sudo npm install qunit-cli and used this line to install jslint sudo npm install jshint

Comment: do what @BrianHenry says. And drop the `sudo`. That's probably not what you want to do. (Although it is the natural thing to do if you are used to `apt-get`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't have the 'grunt-contrib' modules that use qunit and jshint in a grunt task form.  You should be able to check with something like `npm ls | grep contrib`.

I'd suggest, within your project, running:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
```

and

```
npm install grunt-contrib-qunit --save-dev
```

I would've expected some of the other `grunt.loadNpmTasks()`-specified modules to choke too, so I'm a little surprised more errors are not happening.

As for "Warning: Task "compass" not found", there is no 'compass' target in your gruntfile (as there is for `qunit`, `watch`, etc.), so that makes sense.  You'll either want to add in a 'compass' task to do stuff under that name or specify another target to `grunt` on the command-line (or omit any specific target to execute your default `['jshint', 'qunit', 'concat', 'uglify']` tasks).

Comment: I added those lines to my project and got thie eeror after running grunt again.    Traviss-MacBook-Pro-2:GRUNT Travis$ grunt
Running "jshint:files" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "qunit:files" (qunit) task
Warning: 0/0 assertions ran (0ms) Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
Traviss-MacBook-Pro-2:GRUNT Travis$

Comment: Sounds like perhaps qunit expects at least one test, and you may not have any defined?  Not really sure about qunit.  You can configure the qunit task to run with 'force' option (https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-qunit). If qunit is not something you need, though, should be able to remove it from the 'defaults' array (and yank that target out, uninstall it, etc.).  Depends on what you want grunt to be doing for you.